# Can You Customize the 'Send Definition' for Salesforce Sends in Marketing Cloud so it appears in Discover Reports in Analytics Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-definition

I work in the Child business unit account of an Enterprise 2.0 Marketing Cloud account. I have a newsletter that goes out to various audience segments and contains dynamic articles based on each audience segment. In Analytics Studio, I'd like to bring in the 'audience segment' field to parse out the results for that email send, however I'm told I have to pay for a custom report or else buy into Datorama to get this.

As an alternative route, I noticed there might be a workaround by creating separate Send DE's, and separate Salesforce Sends, so that in my Discover report I can pull in the 'Send Definition' to break out the results by 'Send Definition' which would essentially be the audience segment in my case.

This method successfully split out the results, with more effort of course, but the 'Send Definition' is a system created value instead of using the name of the Salesforce Send I created. Is there a way to customize the name of the Salesforce Send so that it appears in the Discover reports instead of it being something like "ISDC_..(fill in with random alphanumeric characters).."

I had it work ONE time but I'm not sure how I got it to work. Looking for advise/suggestions on how to get around this.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach:

- Split your audience in separate Sending DEs based on the values of the audience differentiator field that you already have via filter or query
- add all those DEs to the audience of your send
- in a Discover report add "Data Source" (or audience, not sure how it's called at the moment) as a grouping

This gives you the metrics for the send in total and per data source, which matches your audience.